# How to create a model browser like objects from Model Derivative API metadata

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I am using this call provided by Forge API to get all Model metadata properties.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

I am getting all parent and child objects returned as separate nodes in the json that I am getting in the response. There is no linkage or relationship property saying that object X is a parent of object Y like we get in Model Browser option of Forge Viewer.

[image]

Is there a way possible that we can create this object tree after getting the metadata from Forge Model Derivative API. I really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the buildModelTree mentioned in this thread to rebuild the instance tree hierarchy:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807152/7745569